# R: passing a formula into an function as the first input

Tags: r, function, formula

```
library(RSSL)
set.seed(1)
df <- generateSlicedCookie(1000,expected=FALSE) %>% 
  add_missinglabels_mar(Class~.,0.98)
class_erlr <- EntropyRegularizedLogisticRegression(Class ~., df, lambda=0.01,lambda_entropy = 100)
```

In the `EntropyRegularizedLogisticRegression` function from the `RSSL` package, the example in the documentation passed in the formula `Class ~.` as the input. I was looking at the [source code](https://github.com/cran/RSSL/blob/master/R/EntropyRegularizedLogisticRegression.R), and these are the parameters for the function

```
function (X, y, X_u = NULL, lambda = 0, lambda_entropy = 1, intercept = TRUE, 
          init = NA, scale = FALSE, x_center = FALSE)
```

I tried manually defining what `X, y, X_u` are based on the `df` I generated. But running the following gives me an error with the optimization:

```
y <- df$Class
X <- df[, -1]
ids <- which(is.na(y))
X_u <- X[ids, ]
class_erlr_manual <- EntropyRegularizedLogisticRegression(X = X, y = y, X_u = X_u, lambda=0.01,lambda_entropy = 100)
```

The error reads:

```
Error in optim(w, fn = loss_erlr, gr = grad_erlr, X, y, X_u, lambda = lambda,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

Why does changing the formula input `Class ~.` into `X=X, y =y, X_u = X_u` result in an error? Can anyone point me to where in the source code the formula input is being used?

Comment: In the source, the args are passed to `PreProcessing`.  In that function the first line is `if (is(X, "formula") & is.data.frame(y)) {`.

Comment: @user2554330 I see! I will take a look at `PreProcessing`. Thanks.